# How can I define a struct in (*.cpp) instead (*.h) in a class

Tags: c++, class, struct

I want to define a struct out of the head file.

Below is what I declare in the (*.h)

```
class MyVertex
{
public:
    struct Vertex{};
};
```

How can I define the struct Vertex more detailedly in the (*.cpp)?
I've tried several times with several ways but failed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is you are not declaring the `struct` you are fully defining it.  In order to declare it you need to leave off the `{}`

```
class MyVertex { 
public:
  struct Vertex;
};
```

Once you do that you will be able to define the `struct` members later in the `.h` file or the `.cpp`

```
struct MyVertex::Vertex { 
  ...
};
```